# dependency injection with OSGI

Tags: dependency-injection, osgi, bundle, guice

I have built an application with the dependency framework Guice. Now I will move over to OSGI and started to extend my jars with bundle information.

The main problem, which I currently face is, how to set up the dependency injection correctly. I have bundle A, which exports some packages. Then Bundle B defines a component, which needs some object (class AA) of bundle A injected.

I could set up a service for the class AA in bundle A, which will be injected automatically, but what if bundle A has also a dependency to some class in bundle A, which is maybe not exported. Do I have to set up the second class then also as service, which will not work, because it is not exported.

The following code will show the problem:

Bundle A

```
package test.bundleA.api

public class AA {

   @Inject
   public AA(AInternal someReference) {...}
}




package test.bundleA.internal

public class AInternal {...}
```

Bundle B:

```
package test.bundleB.api

public class ComponentB {

   @Inject
   public ComponentB(AA refToA) {...}
}
```

When I will use any other classes in bundle A from the exported package, do I have then to set up for each of them a service?

What is a common approach to solve the problem of dependency injection inside the bundle and even over bundle boundaries?

Answer (score 2):

If you are independent of using Guice I would recommend to use Eclipse+Bndtools to create your OSGi bundles. With Bndtools, its quite easy to create OSGi bundles and also DI via Annotations. Let's take an example:

You have an interface in bundleA:

```
public interface Greeting {
   String sayHello(String name);
}
```

An implementation in bundleB where `@Component` enables our bundle to use OSGi Declarative Service.

```
@Component
public class ExampleComponent implements Greeting {
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

And in the end a third bundleC where you want to us DI and inject all `Greeting` implementation to a specific component for usage.

```
@Component
public class GreetingCommand {
    private Greeting greetingSvc;

    @Reference
    public void setGreeting(Greeting greetingSvc) {
        this.greetingSvc = greetingSvc;
    }

    public void greet(String name) {
        System.out.println(greetingSvc.sayHello(name));
    }
}
```

As you can see with `@Reference` you indicate that you want to inject an implementation of your `Greeting` interface. The example above uses OSGi Declarative Services in combination with Bndtools. Bndtools itself takes the annotations and creates a XML file needed for OSGi to use Declarative Services. I don't want to go more deep into it. Please see [1] and [2] for more information. Just wanted to show you how DI is made by using declarative services and Bndtools.

[1] http://bndtools.org/

[2] http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Declarative_Services

Comment: christian, thank you for your answer. But if I understood it right, the bndtools just generates the xml for the declarative service, which than can be used by the OSGi framework for service registering. Then I still have the problem that the ExampleComponent (my class AA) does have a dependency to an internal class in its own bundle (AInternal). OSGi cannot create the ExampleComponent when it has no parameterless constructor. I could use an extra setter for this, but that is another story / discussion of DI setter vs. constructor injection

Comment: The interface description is in another bundle. usually you dont put your implementation into the same bundle as your interface. therefore, you just have a dependency to an, lets say, API bundle and the consumer has the same dependency, but never to the implementation bundle. consequently, the consumer never has a direct connection to the implementation itself and that is what DI wants to address, right?!

Comment: I would expect that it does not matter if the interface description is in the same bundle or another. Even if the interface would be in another bundle lets call it AInterface, than still the ExampleComponent (service provider) implementing AInterface will somehow be instantiated by the osgi framework. But ExampleComponent has an additional internal dependency. The framework cannot instantiate that? Am I wrong?

Comment: Right, declarative services does not have a facility for injecting classes from within the same bundle... unless those classes are published as services. But I don't see why anybody would need this. If the class is in the same bundle, then you have full visibility of it and can instantiate with the `new` keyword.

Comment: @NeilBartlett but using `new` it sounds like a violation of the DI concept. Because it decreases the level of testability. If some logic happens in ExamepleComponent and some in AInternal, with `new`it is quite difficult to test ExampleComponent

Comment: I've seen that `AInternal` is actually an implementation class. If you really want to use DI, you should always use interfaces as parameter for the method used to inject instances of that interface implementation. Your testability will be increased as well. Go through the Bndtools tutorial and you will see the advantages.

Comment: "violation of the DI concept." If something is simpler (and new is in this case hugely simpler than DI) than it is better. DI is better than creating a dependency but if you already have this dependency anyway (and you seem to do) then new is much better. Keep it simple ...

Comment: As Peter says, DI is a great idea... until you take it too far. At a certain point it just creates obfuscation. Is there really any sense in testing something separately from the classes which you **know** will always be available?

Comment: Lets assume my bundle B will load some data from somewhere  and transform it to a more useful representation. So my Service interface offers the method getTransformedData. The ExampleComponent implements the service. Inside the ExampleComponent there is a importer for the data and a transformer. The importer by itself depends on a data reader and a factory for some java objects. the transformer has some other dependency for helping the transformation. In the end it is just one bundle, but with quite a big object graph. How would you solve that from a testing perspective?

Comment: Please have a deeper look to OSGi and how it works. Do some tutorials and I think the answer will come by the time. :) I think there are some missing OSGi conceptual knowledge. Sorry, but it's hard then to argue here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a extension library called [Peaberry](http://code.google.com/p/peaberry/) which provide integration Guice with OSGi. There is nice [example](http://code.google.com/p/peaberry/wiki/UserGuide)  how to inject a service bundle into another bundle.

Hope you will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your specific scenario is to define a public *factory* (builder) service/component that you can register with osgi and inject that type.  The factory impl can be defined in the same module, and create the internal type via a 'create' or 'build' method with a return type of a public interface type, but the impl is internal.